# How html5 code rendering under html 4 doctype?

Tags: asp.net, html, kendo-ui

i written html 4 code in my aspx page and  used html 4 Doctype in top of the code and also i using Kendu UI in my project ,kendu written in html 5.The functionality working fine without any error.but my question is how html 5 code rendering under html 4 doctype .

Comment: Browsers are smart, and are used to sites throwing junk at them

Comment: there is nothing do with it.  Even you can use HTML5 features in older browser via Shiv/Shims. doctype is just telling which schema ur using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only effect of doctype strings on browsers is the choice of Quirks Mode vs. Standards Mode vs. Almost Standards Mode, which takes place in a complicated process of [doctype sniffing](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/). Using `<!doctype html>` has practically speaking the same effect as using the HTML 4.01 Strict docype as defined in the spec (though in some more or less obsolete browsers like Netscape there can be a difference).

The choice of doctype has no impact on the interpretation of HTML5 tags. Browsers that support them do so whatever the doctype is (and even in the absence of any doctype).

Answer (score 0):

HTML5, as a markup language, is still HTML4 but with handful of new tags (element types).
I don't think that Kendu UI uses these new element types. It may use new CSS features but CSS and its version implemented by the browser is quite orthogonal to version of HTML.